# Select every second record then determine earliest date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have table that looks like the following

[image]

I have to select every second record per PatientID that would give the following result (my last query returns this result)

[image]

I then have to select the record with the oldest date which would be the following (this is the end result I want)

[image]

What I have done so far: I have a CTE that gets all the data I need

```
WITH cte
AS 
(
    SELECT visit.PatientTreatmentVisitID, mat.PatientMatchID,pat.PatientID,visit.RegimenDate AS VisitDate, 
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY mat.PatientMatchID, pat.PatientID ORDER BY visit.VisitDate ASC) AS RowNumber
    FROM tblPatient pat INNER JOIN tblPatientMatch mat ON mat.PatientID = pat.PatientID
    LEFT JOIN tblPatientTreatmentVisit visit ON visit.PatientID = pat.PatientID
)
```

I then write a query against the CTE but so far I can only return the second row for each patientID

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT PatientTreatmentVisitID,PatientMatchID,PatientID, VisitDate,  RowNumber FROM cte    
) as X
WHERE RowNumber = 2
```

How do I return the record with the oldest date only? Is there perhaps a MIN() function that I could be including somewhere?

Comment: It would help if you specified which RDBMS and version you're using e.g. SQL Server 2008 (or whatever)

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2016

Comment: Throwing that much bold at us does not make the question easier to read. Also in future we prefer data to be formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity add `order desc` on date column and use `TOP` to get the first row only

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM 
(
    SELECT PatientTreatmentVisitID,PatientMatchID,PatientID, VisitDate,  RowNumber FROM cte    
) as X
WHERE RowNumber = 2 
order by VisitDate desc
```

Answer (score 2):

If I follow you correctly, you can just order your existing resultset and retain the top row only.

In standard SQL, you would write this using a `FETCH` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        visit.PatientTreatmentVisitID, 
        mat.PatientMatchID,
        pat.PatientID,
        visit.RegimenDate AS VisitDate, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY mat.PatientMatchID, pat.PatientID ORDER BY visit.VisitDate ASC) AS rn
    FROM tblPatient pat 
    INNER JOIN tblPatientMatch mat ON mat.PatientID = pat.PatientID
    LEFT JOIN tblPatientTreatmentVisit visit ON visit.PatientID = pat.PatientID
) t
WHERE rn = 2
ORDER BY VisitDate
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```

This syntax is supported in Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server (and possibly other databases).

Answer (score 2):

If you need to get oldest date from all selected dates (every second row for each patient ID) then you can try `window function Min:`

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT *, MIN(VisitDate) OVER (Order By VisitDate) MinDate
  FROM 
   (
    SELECT    PatientTreatmentVisitID,PatientMatchID,PatientID, VisitDate,  
    RowNumber FROM cte  
   ) as X
   WHERE RowNumber = 2 
) Y
WHERE VisitDate=MinDate
```

Or you can use SELECT TOP statement. The `SELECT TOP clause` allows you to limit the number of rows returned in a query result set:

```
SELECT TOP 1 PatientTreatmentVisitID,PatientMatchID,PatientID, VisitDate FROM  
   (
     SELECT *
     FROM 
     (
      SELECT PatientTreatmentVisitID,PatientMatchID,PatientID, VisitDate,  
      RowNumber FROM cte    
     ) as X
   WHERE RowNumber = 2 
  ) Y
  ORDER BY VisitDate
```

Comment: Graaf, do you try query?